# Nearby Places search gives a random result rather than a specific result

Tags: android, geolocation, google-places-api, location-based-service

When I first run my app, on cicking on a particular Place Type, it generates every tpe of nearby place like: atm, malls, food,schools etc. within my specified mile radius.
**Code for Places Activity:**

```
package www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.List;

import www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap.model.Places;
import www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap.parsers.PlacesJSONParser;


public class PlacesActivity extends ListActivity {

    TextView placeName;
    TextView placeVicinity;
    TextView placeStatus;

    String locationType;
    String myUrl;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // List<FetchLocationTask> tasks;


    List<Places> placesList;

    String lat, lng;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_places);

        // Initialize the TextView for vertical Scrolling
        placeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_title);
        placeVicinity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vicinity);
        placeStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.openNow);

        // tasks = new ArrayList<>();


        //locationFetcher();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            locationType = (extras.getString("TAG")).toString();
            lat = extras.getString("lat").toString();
            lng = extras.getString("lng").toString();
        } else {
            // set default value for now
            locationType = "atm";
        }

        myUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="
                + lat + ","
                + lng
                + "&radius="
                + getString(R.string.radius)
                + "&types="
                + locationType
                + "&sensor=true&key="
                + getString(R.string.google_maps_key);


        myUrl = myUrl.replaceAll(" ", "_");
        //Log.d("generated URL: ", myUrl);

        requestData(myUrl);

    }

    protected void updatePlaces() {
        if (placesList.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        PlacesListAdapter adapter = new PlacesListAdapter(this, R.layout.item_vicinity, placesList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_places, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, locationType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            requestData(myUrl);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void requestData(String uri) {
        /*
            Methods for Volley
            Comment out this block and Uncomment AsyncTask to Use the AsyncTask block
            The Volley Library uses less lines of code than the AsyncTask
         */

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(uri,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        placesList = PlacesJSONParser.parseFeed(response);
                        updatePlaces();
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {
                        //Toast.makeText(PlacesActivity.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(PlacesActivity.this, "Please Check your network connection and" +
                                " refresh again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        // add the request to queue
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(request);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlacesActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading locations..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        //Methods using AsyncTask, Uncomment if using AsyncTask
//        FetchLocationTask myTask = new FetchLocationTask();
//        myTask.execute(uri);
    }

    /*
        Replacing the AsyncTask with Volley.
        To Use the AsyncTask, Comment out the Volley Method inside the RequestData() Method
         and Uncomment AsyncTask with the corresponding methods
     */

    /*private class FetchLocationTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Places>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
                //updatePlaces();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlacesActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading locations..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Places> doInBackground(String... params) {
            String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
            placesList = PlacesJSONParser.parseFeed(content);
            Log.d("results : ", content);
            return placesList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Places> result) {

            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            if (result == null) {
                Toast.makeText(PlacesActivity.this, "Web service not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
           placesList = result;
           updatePlaces();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
          //  updatePlaces(values[0]);
        }
    }*/


}












**Code for Restaurant.java**

    package www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Restaurant extends FragmentActivity {
        MyLocation mLocation;
        String lat, lng;
        String[] keywords;
        //String restaurants;
        //private int defautltId, restaurantId;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_map);
    //        defautltId = R.drawable.ic_default;
    //        restaurantId = R.drawable.ic_restaurant;

            keywords = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.keywords);

            mLocation = new MyLocation(this);
            //fetch location method
            locationFetcher();
            //keywords[0]

            if (isOnline()) {

    //                   Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "You clicked "+ keywords[position]
    //                           + " from " + lat + " , " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlacesActivity.class)
                        .putExtra("TAG", keywords[0])
                        .putExtra("lat", lat)
                        .putExtra("lng", lng);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Network Isn't Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        protected boolean isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void locationFetcher() {

            if (mLocation.canGetLocation()) {
                //mLocation.getLocation();
                double latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
                lng = String.valueOf(longitude);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "LOCATION NOT ACQUIRED,TURN ON A PROVIDER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    }
```

**Code for the cardview where the restaurant.java is first added to the cardview stack:**

```
package www.uneditedmap.com.locationandmap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by null on 28/02/2015.
 */
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public static String FAV = "New Activity";

    List<EndangeredItem> mItems;
    //    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;


    public GridAdapter() {
        super();
        //inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
//        this.context=context;
//        this.mItems=mItems;
//        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mItems = new ArrayList<EndangeredItem>();
        EndangeredItem species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Restaurant");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.restaurant);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Churches");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.church);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Laundry");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.laundry);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Schools");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.school);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Cinemas");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.cinema);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Hospitals");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.hospital);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Tech Centers");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.hubs);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Clubs");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.clubs);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Fashion House");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.fashion);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Banks");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.bank);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Atms");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.atm);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Sport Centers");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.sportcenters);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Supermarkets");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.supermarket);
        mItems.add(species);

        species = new EndangeredItem();
        species.setName("Sitouts");
        species.setThumbnail(R.drawable.sitouts);
        mItems.add(species);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        EndangeredItem nature = mItems.get(i);
        viewHolder.tvspecies.setText(nature.getName());
        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvspecies;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvspecies = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_species);
            imgThumbnail.setOnClickListener(this);
            //to enable user clicking long n the cardview image
            imgThumbnail.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = null;
            switch (getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(context, Restaurant.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(context, TestIntent.class);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(context, TestIntent.class);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent = new Intent(context, TestIntent.class);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    intent = new Intent(context, TestIntent.class);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    intent = new Intent(context, TestIntent.class);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    intent = new Intent(context, TestIntent.class);

                    break;
                default:
                    intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    break;
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
//            Intent intent;
//            intent = new Intent(context, Favourites.class);
//            intent.putExtra(FAV, R.id.img_thumbnail);
//            context.startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(context, "added to favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**My String Array:**

```
<string-array name="keywords">
        <item>Restaurants</item>
        <item>Churches</item>
        <item>Laundry</item>
        <item>Schools</item>
        <item>Cinemas</item>
        <item>Hospitals</item>
        <item>Tech Centers</item>
        <item>Clubs</item>
        <item>Fashion House</item>
        <item>Banks</item>
        <item>Atms</item>
        <item>Sport Centers</item>
        <item>Supermarkets</item>
        <item>Sitouts</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: How do I make it generate only food and bar

Comment: This question would be a lot shorter and clearer if you omitted all the Java code, and simply gave a URL of a request that wasn't giving the results you expect.  Your Java code isn't really relevant here.  Your question is really just about the Places API request.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Google API to get food and bars around the location,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=ADD_LATITUDE,ADD_LONGITUDE&radius=5000&types=food,bar&sensor=true&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAP_BROWSER_KEY
```

- Enable GooglePlacesAPI from [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis).
- Generate *Browser Key* **not** *Android Key*, it will not work in this case.

Add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

also add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Response:**

You will get **JSON response** when you enter URL in browser.

Comment: thank you but plz go thru the code u'd see that i've done everything you said. My problem is that I cannot get just food and bars. It's every type the call generates when I run the app. My place type is a string array.

Comment: What are you passing in `type`? What is the value of `locationType`.

Comment: please checkout my Restaurant class in the latter part of my first code. u'd see where I parsed the intent class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your URL String that searches for specific places.

String loginURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=19.9974,73.7876113&radius=2000&type=SBH&name=atm&key=API_KEY_HERE";

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Nearby Search request contains `types=Restaurants`, but that isn't a valid value for the `types` parameter.  The valid values are in Table 1 of [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1) documentation.  E.g. instead of `Restaurants` you want `restaurant`.

A secondary issue is that `types` is a deprecated parameter.  You're only passing one type at a time, so you can easily switch to the fully supported `type` parameter.  See the deprecation notice in the [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) documentation.